# how to have the right scrollbar on a web page scroll only the middle pane

Tags: html, css

If you look at messages page in facebook, there is a header and below it there are three sections. The scroll bar controls the middle section and the left and right sections remain static.  How do I implement the same behavior on my webpage?  That is everything remains fixed and the scroll bar only controls the middle section?  By the way, Facebook's implementation does not work properly in Chrome and in FF stops working when Firebug is turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set anything special on the center section. Every block element you want to remain stationary needs to have `position: fixed;`.

eg

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      header {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10; /* keeps the header over the content as the content gets scrolled */
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;
      }
      #sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 120px; /* add height + padding of header */
        left: 0;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      #content {
        margin: 120px 0 0 170px; /* add adjacent elements' size + padding */
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      This will stay on the top of the browser window.
    </header>
    <div id="sidebar">
      This will stay on the left.
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      This will scroll normally.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Preacher Thanks! when scrolling, my middle content rolls over the header. How do i force it to behave and stay below the header?

Comment: You can fiddle with the z-index of the header. Check the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Preacher, thanks! the z-index solves the above. However there is a footer also and the content of the middle panel extends all the way to the bottom of the page now and goes over the footer. Even if its z-index is less than that of the bottom panel. Even if the z-index was working, it would just cover the content at the bottom of the middle panel.

Comment: I had position:relative for the middle panel, once I removed that, the footer problem was solved.

Comment: The z-index solution is not going to cut it. Now the top content of the central div is hidden behind the header. Do you know how to move the body div or its containing divs down to start below the header?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you put a screenshot of the issue in your question?

Comment: It was my bad. I had not set the top margin of the center panel. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: but there remains one last issue.  I have the borders of the center panel rounded.  this looks fine when the page is rendered, but as the user scrolls, the panel moves up and the rounded corners disappear.

Comment: @Preacher I marked your answer as 'the answer' and added a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113592/how-to-keep-the-rounded-corners-from-disappearing-in-a-scrolled-div regarding the rounded corners.  Many thanks!