# how to keep the rounded corners from disappearing in a scrolled div

Tags: html, css

Please see the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/8fQjB/23/

I want the hd div to always stay on top. And the content div to be scrollable via the page scrollbar. The answer at [how to have the right scrollbar on a web page scroll only the middle pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108089/how-to-have-the-right-scrollbar-on-a-web-page-scroll-only-the-middle-pane) does that.  However I need the top rounded corners of the content div not to disappear while the user  scrolls up.  As the div moves up, these corners move up also behind the hd. I need the text just to scroll and the corners to stay stationary.

Many thanks!